Further explain why every closed set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is boundary of some other set
I've stumbled upon the following problem.

Let $X$ be a closed subset $\mathbb{R}^n$. Prove that there is $V\subset X$ such that $\partial V= X$.

@NielsJ.Diepeveen has provided a result which proves the statement quite easily.
(Every closed set in $\mathbb R^2$ is boundary of some other subset)
Here's how far I've gone through their proof:
Let $Y$ be a topological space that can be split into two disjoint dense sets, $E$ and $D$. In $\mathbb{R}^n$, I claim that we could choose $E$ to be the set of point with rational coordinates because $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. Likewise, $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is also dense in $\mathbb{R}$, thus we could choose $D=E^{c}$.
Let us define $V=X\setminus \left(D\cap X^{\circ}\right)$. The most intuitive reasoning I have for this is to remove a lot of elements from the interior of $X$. Either way, $V\subset X$ by definition, which implies that $\overline{V}\subset \overline{X}=X$ (because $X$ is closed). We can know use the fact that $\overline{V}=V^{\circ}\cup \partial V$ to conclude that $\partial V \subset X$.
I'm having trouble to reason through the second half of the proof. The main idea is to show that $\overline{V}=X$ and that $V^{\circ}=\varnothing$. By the argument on the paragraph above, we'd conclude that $\partial V =X$.
@olaphus pointed out that it is possible to show that $V=(X^{\circ}\cap E)\cup \partial X$. Here's my attempt.
$$V=X\setminus \left(D\cap X^{\circ}\right) = X\cap\left(E\cup (X^{\circ})^{c}\right)=(X\cap E)\cup (X \cap (X^{\circ})^{c})).$$
I'm not sure how this expression is equal to the given one. As for the second equality, @NielsJ.Diepeveen claims that $Y\setminus X$ is dense in $Y\setminus X^{\circ}$ and $D\cap X^{\circ}$ is dense in $X^{\circ}$. I don't know where to start to begin proving these.

Let us prove that $V=(X^\circ \cap E)\cup \partial X$.
Let $x\in V$, then $x\in X$ and if $x\notin \partial X$, then $x\in X^\circ$ (since $X$ is closed). However, $x\in V$, and so $x\notin D$, which means $x\in E$, and so finally $x\in E\cap X^\circ$.
We have proved $V\subset (X^\circ \cap E)\cup \partial X$. Conversely, let $x\in \partial X$, then $x\in V$ by definition of $V$.
Instead, if $x\in X^\circ \cap E$, then $x\notin D\cap X^\circ$, and so $x\in X\setminus (D\cap X^\circ)$.
Now we observe that
$$cl(V)=cl((X^\circ \cap E)\cup \partial X)\supseteq cl(X^\circ \cap E)\cup cl(\partial X)=X^\circ \cup \partial X=X \implies cl(V)\supseteq X \implies cl(V)=X.$$
Let $x\in V^\circ$, then it there exists a open ball $U$ centered at $x$ such that $U\subseteq V$. We observe  $U\subseteq  X^\circ$ and since $U\subseteq V=X\setminus (X^\circ \cap D)$, then $U\subseteq E$, that is a contradiction since $E$ is a numerable set. Therefore $V^\circ =\emptyset$ and then $\partial V=X$.
